# error: Multiple arb files with the same 'en' locale detected

Tags: android, flutter, locale, lib, arb

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQZX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks6jc.png)

Hi I'm getting this error messege on my flutter app, in my lib folder I10n I have these four file in which 3 are arb's please help me with it. please look at the Image and my error is this:

C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 1 error:

Exception: Multiple arb files with the same 'en' locale detected.
Ensure that there is exactly one arb file for each locale.
Process finished with exit code 1

I have not tried anything as I'm not a developer but I need suggestions and resolution. Thank You